# Django model order_by speed

Tags: database, django, database-performance

I'm working on a blogging website using a django server. In my model, I have the following code:

```
class PopularBlog(Blog):
  class Meta:
    ordering = ["-date_created", "-num_likes"]
    proxy = True
```

Basically, `date_created` never changes for a Blog. However, `num_likes` might change pretty frequently.

Is the PopularBlog table modified every time when any blog's `num_likes` is updated? How is the performance?

Comment: This is an odd question, but I don't think it deserves closing. We should be advising the poster to learn about how database indexes work, rather than closing without comment.

Comment: Yeah can you give me some idea of how database index works? I'm just afraid if I keep a table like this, every time num_likes of a blog gets updated, the PopularBlog table needs to be updated and the operation would be really slow. Thanks!

Comment: Plus I don't understand why ppl voted down on this question... Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a question about Django, but a question about databases. StackOverflow isn't really the place to go into the ins and outs of database indexes, but you should at least be aware that this is *exactly* the sort of thing that databases are good at. Just updating a single row of a table is nothing, and even if you've defined an index on the `num_likes` column it'll be updated extremely quickly unless you have millions of records.

Comment: Ok. I guess I only need to worry about this problem when stuff needs to scale up. Thanks!